# How to play recorded audio in Flutter using just_audio and record plugins?

Tags: flutter, audio-recording, just-audio

I am using the [record](https://pub.dev/packages/record) to record a voice note in M4A format.
I am using the [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) to play the recording.

The recording plays perfectly on Android, but not on iOS.

**I have tried the following:**

- Recording the audio on Android, pushing it to a database, and then
  fetching the same file on iOS. I was able to play the file on iOS.
- Playing an M4A audio file downloaded from the internet on iOS. I was
  able to play the file.

But I am still unable to play the recorded audio directly on iOS.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you figure it out? I have the same problem